Probability that a random graph on $n$ vertices contains a triangle - what's gone wrong?
I know that a graph containing a triangle (or any complete graph) is an extremal problem, so there shouldn't be a result like the following, so could someone have a look and try and see where I've gone wrong?
I am considering random graphs where each edge is present with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.
Given selected vertices $\{a,b,c\}$, the probability of a random graph as above containing the triangle with vertices a,b and c is $(1/2)^3$. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ choices of the set $\{a,b,c\}$, so the probability of a random graph $G$ on n vertices containing a triangle is therefore $\binom{n}{3} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3$?
This doesn't even tend to 1! I am really not great at probability

That's expected number of triangles, not probability of having a triangle. Probability of having a triangle is hard to compute, as events for different triangles are dependent. Do you need the number, or just to show that it goes to $1$?

I expect that this is a duplicate. The exact probability is hard to compute.

OEIS: A213434 gives the number of triangle-free graphs.

@lulu I saw this. My problem was self motivated, I just stumbled upon this as a line of reasoning and it confused me because "probability that there is a triangle" sounds like an extremal problem which shouldn't have a nice solution like I "calculated"

@DanielMathias Is there one of these for any other complete graphs?

@mihaild Thanks, that explains it. I was trying to find the number, I've seen the other post linked by lulu which shows how it can be shown to tend to $1$. I was trying to find the number to calculate a different expectation though so I will see if this can be transferred. Thank you again!

@SamuelHitchcock lower bound that still tends to $1$ is much easier to find. Group vertices by $3$, and computer probability that none of the group forms a triangle - these events are independent.
